# while running rake db:create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using ruby-3.1.0 and in mac this error is coming

```
rake aborted!
Aborting startup since the following application dependencies are not installed: identify
```

This error is coming there:

```
/Users/nirmal.kumar/Documents/magplus/service-plus/app/models/publish_app.rb:4:in `check_dependencies!' 
/Users/nirmal.kumar/Documents/magplus/service-plus/config/initializers/dependency_check.rb:1:in `\<top (required)\>'
/Users/nirmal.kumar/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:667:in `load' 
/Users/nirmal.kumar/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:667:in `block in load_config_initializer'
/Users/nirmal.kumar/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.8/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:208:in `instrument' 
/Users/nirmal.kumar/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:666:in `load_config_initializer'
/Users/nirmal.kumar/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:620:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>' 
/Users/nirmal.kumar/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:619:in `each'
/Users/nirmal.kumar/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:619:in `block in <class:Engine>' 
/Users/nirmal.kumar/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
/Users/nirmal.kumar/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run' 
/Users/nirmal.kumar/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
/Users/nirmal.kumar/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `each' 
/Users/nirmal.kumar/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `tsort_each_child'
/Users/nirmal.kumar/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers' 
/Users/nirmal.kumar/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/application.rb:372:in `initialize!'
/Users/nirmal.kumar/Documents/magplus/service-plus/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>' 
/Users/nirmal.kumar/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.12/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:38:in `require'
/Users/nirmal.kumar/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.12/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:38:in `require' 
/Users/nirmal.kumar/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/application.rb:348:in `require_environment!'
/Users/nirmal.kumar/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/application.rb:506:in `block in run_tasks_blocks' 
/Users/nirmal.kumar/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/exe/rake:27:in `\<top (required)\>'
/Users/nirmal.kumar/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `eval' 
/Users/nirmal.kumar/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `\<main\>
```

I tried to run bundle update also it is still not .

Comment: Can you include the start of your `app/models/publish_app.rb`?

Comment: Can you please share the actual error message which should be in top of this stacktrace.

Comment: @Skenvy you want code inside this file app/models/publish_app.rb

Comment: @spickermann 
rake aborted!
Aborting startup since the following application dependencies are not installed: identify
/Users/solomon.j/Documents/magplus/service-plus/app/models/publish_app.rb:4:in `check_dependencies!'
/Users/solomon.j/Documents/magplus/service-plus/config/initializers/dependency_check.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/solomon.j/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:667:in `load'
/Users/solomon.j/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:667:in `block in load_config_initializer'
This is the error

Comment: Are you using [identify](https://rubygems.org/gems/identify) somewhere without having installed it?